# Get icon of a process (like in gnome-system-monitor) to be used with Gtk and python

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, process, gtk

I have been working on a project which involves me to get the icon from the icon theme used on Linux so that I can use it with the Gtk Pixbuf like how Gnome-system-monitor displays the icon for all the process, the same thing I want to achieve. Any ideas about how to do this?

I am using python with Gtk on PopOS 20.10.

Answer (score 1):

Gio.AppInfo in the Gtk library stack is a good point to start.

If you are looking for the approach that is used by the gnome-system-monitor then the prettytable.c file will the one you need to check.

There is one more approach, scanning the `/usr/share/application/` directory and creating a file monitor for this directory. All icons of the application are that are in the menu can be found here.

Answer (score 0):

There is **GtkIconTheme** using it we can get the list of the icon of the default theme and then using the name of the process to get the icon. The other approach is to use **Gio.AppInfo** which is kind of wrapper to the **.desktop** entry files.
One more approach would be to use the *Wnck* module to the currently active windows which can easily give the icon of the process by its PID or Name.

Gnome-system-monitor uses all of these methods to get the icon for the processes.

For python3

```
from gi.repository import Gtk,Gio,Wnck,re

# using Gtk.IconTheme
icon_theme=g.IconTheme().get_default()
theme_icon_list=icon_theme.list_icons(None)
# now you can do pretty much any trick for matching up 
if name in theme_icon_list:
    icon=icon_theme.load_icon(name, <size>, 0)

# using Wnck
screen=Wnck.Screen.get_default()
screen.force_update()
# you can use either pid(recommended) or name or both
for window in screen.get_windows():
    if pid==win.get_pid() or re.search(pname,window.get_name(),re.IGNORECASE):
        icon=window.get_icon().scale_simple(20,20,2) #scale_simple is for scaling

# using Gio.AppInfo
gio_apps=Gio.AppInfo.get_all() # appinfo list 
for app in apps:
    # not always the process name the display names are same so use you own tricks using .get_executable() or .get_commandline()
    if name==app.get_display_name(): 
        gicon=app.get_icon()
        if gicon:
           icon=icon_theme.lookup_by_gicon(gicon,16,g.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SIZE).load_icon()
```